# Android - Trigger manually onCreate method on class derived from SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I would like to create my database tables on application startup if database is not created so the calls to create tables and insert initial values on these tables are put within OnCreate method in the class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper.

The problem is that on application startup, I do not perform any operation with the database (I only created a new instance of the class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper from my main activity java class) so OnCreate method is not triggered automatically and hence that database is not created.

The constructor of the class (DBHelper) thats extends SQLiteOpenHelper is (Context comes from app's main activity java class):

```
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.activityContext = context;
}
```

So in order to trigger onCreate method and force to database be created if it does not exist, once I have created a new instance of the class that extends SQLLiteOpenHelper:

```
    MyDbHelper = new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);
```

I call below method:

```
    MyDbHelper.SetWritableDb();
```

which performs the following:

```
this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Once above sentece is executed, then OnCreate method is triggered and my database is created through the CREATE statements. Ok, no problem until here.

After creating database tables, I then set some default values to some tables, that is, I perform some inserts but an exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
```

I think the problem is that when inserting default values to some tables using below method (this method is called from the class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper):

```
public final boolean BulkInsert(Context context, DBHelper dbHelper)
{
    boolean result = false;

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    .....
}
```

getWritableDatabase is called again so database is trying to get blocked again by:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked
```

and then it crashes....

How can I get rid of this? I need my SQLite database to be created (if it is not already created) at main activity when my app starts up.

Comment: "I perform some inserts" -- how do you do this? This code should be just plain `SQLiteDatabase` calls in your `onCreate()` method. See [this sample `SQLiteOpenHelper`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Database/ConstantsROWID/src/com/commonsware/android/constants/DatabaseHelper.java) for an example of something that works.

Comment: @CommonsWare I perform the inserts based on SQLiteOpenHelper, similar to the sample you have provided, that is, I create a ContentValues object, put the data and then doing the typical insert. I think the problem is that there is two consecutive calls to getWritableDatabase....

Answer (score 2):

As you know, `onCreate()` gets triggered by `getWritableDatabase()`.

You cannot call `getWritableDatabase()` inside the `onCreate()` call. Doing so leads to the "called recursively" exception. Use the `SQLiteDatabase` object that gets supplied as a parameter to `onCreate()` instead of calling `getWritableDatabase()`.

The other issue about `getDatabaseLocked()` - I'm guessing it's a NPE and caused by you supplying a `null` or otherwise invalid `Context` to `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor.

Comment: I am not calling getWritableDatase() inside the OnCreate() method. I call getWritableDatabase from the app's main activity java class after instantiating the class in order to force create database for first time. Creating a new instance and entering in the constructor is not triggering OnCreate method so I need to force it by calling getWritableDatabase.

Comment: You're calling `getWritableDatabase()` in a method that is called from `onCreate()`. The outermost `getWritableDatabase()` has not finished yet.

Comment: Yes, but when I perform the bulkInsert, but the first getWritableDatabase() is not called in a method that is called from OnCreate(). The first one (outermost), is from the app's main activity java class once I create the instance in order to force databasa creation for first time.

Comment: My problem is that when I create the new instance, it enters in the DBHelper constructor where it is performed: super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); but I would like at this point, OnCreate to be called but it isn't. that's my problem. I want it to be called so my database creates on app startup time and not later when I do some database operations such as inserts, etc.

Comment: As I have seen database is created on the emulator but it is empty. My database tables are not created as OnCreate method is never triggered. OnCreate method is never invoked even if the database does not exist. Any ideas?